# Odd Reflector Decompile with Invalid Token Error

Tags: c#, .net, reflector, .net-reflector

Would some kind person help me sort out the output of .Net Reflector v6.5 that does not compile?  I think that the symbols are out of whack but global search and replace might fix that.  I don't get the odd class definition.  Ideas?

```
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <ApplicationTaskIterator>d__0 : IEnumerable<ApplicationTask>, IEnumerable, IEnumerator<ApplicationTask>, IEnumerator, IDisposable
    {
        private int <>1__state;
        private ApplicationTask <>2__current;
        public SessionMetrics <>3__sm;
        public Dictionary<int, ThreadMetrics> <>7__wrap3;
        public Dictionary<int, ThreadMetrics>.ValueCollection.Enumerator <>7__wrap4;
        public ApplicationTask <currentTask>5__1;
        public ThreadMetrics <tm>5__2;
        public SessionMetrics sm;

        [DebuggerHidden]
        public <ApplicationTaskIterator>d__0(int <>1__state)
        {
            this.<>1__state = <>1__state;
        }

        private bool MoveNext()
        {
            try
            {
                switch (this.<>1__state)
                {
                    case 0:
                        this.<>1__state = -1;
                        Monitor.Enter(this.<>7__wrap3 = ThreadMetrics._allThreadMetrics);
                        this.<>1__state = 1;
                        this.<>7__wrap4 = ThreadMetrics._allThreadMetrics.Values.GetEnumerator();
                        this.<>1__state = 2;
                        while (this.<>7__wrap4.MoveNext())
                        {
                            this.<tm>5__2 = this.<>7__wrap4.Current;
                            if ((((this.<tm>5__2._managedThread.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped) || object.ReferenceEquals(this.<tm>5__2._managedThread, Thread.CurrentThread)) || ((this.<currentTask>5__1 = this.<tm>5__2.CurrentApplicationTask) == null)) || ((this.sm != null) && !this.<currentTask>5__1.CurrentSessionMetrics.SessionGUID.Equals(this.sm.SessionGUID)))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                            this.<currentTask>5__1.Active = !this.<tm>5__2.Suspended;
                            this.<>2__current = this.<currentTask>5__1;
                            this.<>1__state = 3;
                            return true;
                        Label_010C:
                            this.<>1__state = 2;
                        }
                        this.<>1__state = 1;
                        this.<>7__wrap4.Dispose();
                        this.<>1__state = -1;
                        Monitor.Exit(this.<>7__wrap3);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        goto Label_010C;
                }
                return false;
            }
            fault
            {
                ((IDisposable) this).Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Used like this:

```
    internal static IEnumerable<ApplicationTask> ApplicationTaskIterator(SessionMetrics sm)
    {
        return new <ApplicationTaskIterator>d__0(-2) { <>3__sm = sm };
    }
```

Comment: I also find the interesting fault keyword. I just wonder what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply what the C# compiler transforms a method containing `yield return` statements to.

If you want to make the code compile, you can either try to decipher what the method is doing and recreate the original version with `yield return` statements; or you can rename the class and all members to valid C# names.

---

The original method probably looked like this:

```
internal static IEnumerable<ApplicationTask> ApplicationTaskIterator(SessionMetrics sm)
{
    lock (ThreadMetrics._allThreadMetrics)
    {
        foreach (var tm in ThreadMetrics._allThreadMetrics.Values)
        {
            if (tm._managedThread.ThreadState != ThreadState.Stopped)
            {
                if (!object.ReferenceEquals(tm._managedThread, Thread.CurrentThread))
                {
                    ApplicationTask currentTask;
                    if ((currentTask = tm.CurrentApplicationTask) != null)
                    {
                        if (sm == null || !currentTask.CurrentSessionMetrics.SessionGUID.Equals(sm.SessionGUID))
                        {
                            currentTask.Active = !tm.Suspended;
                            yield return currentTask;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, the yield keyword is great - I should have been using iterators.  Thank you for the information and new ideas.
-Mike

Comment: BTW, replacing the compiler generated class and the stub method to call it with your method did work.  Thanks again.

Comment: As an aside, we (Red Gate) are aware of the fact that Reflector doesn't currently handle yield return, and it's on our list of things to sort out.